# Checking Image support for phone in android

Tags: android, android-image

In Android , How we can check whether or not phone supports HD or Ultra HD Image or video. Like we can check internet connection

```
private boolean isNetworkConnected() {
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null;
}
```

**Note:** I have to only check whether phone support HD Ultra HD Image or Video or Not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out these link, let us know if they work out for what you need

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html